# Google Maps with React - "Required props loadingElement or googleMapURL is missing. You need to provide both of them"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, markers

Afternoon all, I am trying to render a google-map (with pins or markers) in REACT - I have been following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@morgannegagne/google-maps-with-react-951c12b723ad

However I keep getting the same error:

"Required props loadingElement or googleMapURL is missing. You need to provide both of them"

I KNOW it isn't my googleAPI key as have another basic g-map on the site I am building and it renders fine. But in the section where I am trying to add 'Travel Article' pins to a gmap - its proving tricky: The code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ArticleMarker from "./ArticleMarker";
import ArticleMapContainer from "./ArticleMapContainer";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  } from 'react-google-maps';

const ArticlesMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>{

  const markers = props.articles.map( article =>
                <ArticleMarker
                  key={article.uid}
                  doctor={article}
                  location={{lat: article.closestArticle.lat, lng: article.closestArticle.lon}}
                />);
  return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={14}
        center={ { lat:  42.3601, lng: -71.0589 } }
        >
        {markers}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
))

export default ArticlesMap;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error

> Required props loadingElement or googleMapURL is missing. You need to
>   provide both of them

occurs since *props*:

- `googleMapURL: String` - [Google Maps API Url](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)
- `loadingElement: ReactElement` - element which is getting rendered until Google Maps library is finished loading

are *mandatory* for [`withScriptjs` HOC](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/withScriptjs.md)

For example:

```
<ArticlesMap 
  googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=--YOUR-KEY-GOES-HERE--"
  loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
  mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
/>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q70l4w160q)

Comment: Thanks bro. your script just saved my life =))

Answer (score 6):

If you are using multiple libraries such as react-google-maps for maps and react-places-autocomplete for autocomplete search, then you have to load the google api only once.

For that,  you can add the script in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-API-KEY&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"></script>
```

secondly, in your map component, dont use withScript js i.e.

```
export default (withGoogleMap(Map));
```

thirdly, remove googleMapURL and loadingElement from the props.

this will load the script only once from index.html

CHEERS

Comment: this was the answer to my specific scenario. <3<3<3 thanks <3<3<3

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful. I found that when working with the '@react-google-maps/api' library you can include the Google map libraries in the useJsApiLoader hook. I was getting the following error:

> Did you include prop libraries={['drawing']} in the URL? undefined

Here is my example code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, DrawingManager } from '@react-google-maps/api';

export default function InteractiveMap() {
  const key = "fullysickgoogleapikeyhere"

  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: 'google-map-script',
    googleMapsApiKey: key,
    libraries: ["geometry", "drawing", "places"]
  })

  const center = {
    lat: -28,
    lng: 153.39
  }

  const containerStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '70vh'
  };

  const drawingOnLoad = drawingManager => {
    console.log(drawingManager)
  }

  const onPolygonComplete = polygon => {
    console.log(polygon)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      {isLoaded ? (
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={12}
          onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}
        >
          <DrawingManager
            onLoad={drawingOnLoad}
            onPolygonComplete={onPolygonComplete}
          />
        </GoogleMap>
      ) : <></>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

It was mentioned in the docs but in a spot which was not really relevant to what  was looking for but it got me up and running. [React Google Maps Api](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#standalonesearchbox)

You do get a performance warning in the Console but this can be updated to meet your requirements.

Comment: You don't need to use `useJsApiLoader`. You can use `LoadScript`,  and set `libraries={["geometry", "drawing", "places"]}` as a prop in the `LoadScript` tag. Also it wont get the performance warning this way!